# How may a Blue Card applicant bring non-EU unmarried partner to Poland

Tags: immigration, family, europe, poland

I am trying to find out how I can bring my unmarried partner to Poland to live with me. I am in the process of handing in my documents for a Blue Card application.

I am a New Zealand citizen.

I found the following website which mentions the process, but I am unsure if this is still applicable and if it is the easiest method.

https://www.euraxess.pl/poland/information-assistance/entry-conditions/information-non-european-citizens/coming-family

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate if you are Polish, or some other non-Polish EU/EEA/Swiss national (this is the best case), or a non-EU national.

Comment: @MartinBonner a blue card holder is necessarily a non-EU national.

Comment: @phoog D'oh!  I missed that.

Comment: @MartinBonner I have clarified my nationality in the question.

Answer (score 1):

No one answered my question, so I thought I would relay how the process was handled.

I was required to sign a contract with a notary which stipulated I was paying my partner around 500 PLN per month. After this we went to the tax office to pay tax on this income (counted over the duration of my existing work permit, which was 3 years).

After submitting this to the tax office, we supplied the contract and the tax receipt to the immigration office.

My partner now holds a temporary residence permit, the only condition being that they are not allowed to work.

Comment: +1, thanks for the report! It means your partner did not qualify for the regular spouse status (but for another type of residence permit) as I think this should give them the right to work in Poland, correct?

Comment: Correct, that's the case because we are cohabiting rather than married. Poland does not recognise these types of relationships.